# Create persistent live usb from physical or virtual machine

Tags: live-usb, persistence

When creating a persistent live USB from a Linux distro, it appears to be impossible to upgrade the kernel and certain other low-level features. Is it possible to install and configure a Linux install, either physically or in a VM, and then create a persistent USB Live drive from that?

What I'm attempting to do is create a usb environment that already contains the latest kernel, and then configure development tools on the persistence partition.

Answer (score 0):

Most live USBs consist of a compressed root image that is after booting combined with a writable partition, this was done to save space and bandwidth and allow the use of non-writable media for the boot system.

There's no reason why you can't take an image of a real system onto a usb and boot that (so long as you have space), such a system would be fully upgradable.

it's possible boot and run a system had drive over a usb cable, replacing the hard drive with some other writable storage (such as flash) should be possible.

Performance may suffer due to the way flash is writtenn, turning on `noatime` in the mount options will probably help durability and performance.

Comment: Would the drive itself be bootable or would it be specific to the machine it was installed upon? What I'm looking for is a familiar environment on any hardware (with sufficient RAM) I come across.

Comment: that depends if the install was generic or specially tailored.  if you install a good selection of video and network drivers and don't build software for specific processor models it should be portable.